# Get specific attributes from database using sequelize model query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have red the documentation of sequelize but could not get the idea/concept i wanted ,I don't want just one attribute to be shown.
We have the following syntax to get the attributes we need

```
Model.findAll({
    attributes:['foo','bar]          
})
```

In my case I have many attributes in single table , I just want to hide one attribute.Is there any way in sequelize that we define the attribute which we don't want to see and get all other by default..

For Example....

```
    Model.findAll({
       attributes:hide foo , show all other attributes
})
```

AnyOne Can help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below syntax.

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: {
    exclude: ['foo'] // hide this
  }
});
```

You can also exclude fields on model level by adding in their default scope like below.

```
const Model = sequelize.define('model',{
  secretColumn: Sequelize.STRING,
  //... and other columns
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: { exclude: ['secretColumn'] }
  }
});
```